# How to send/receive message from facebook messenger in python

Tags: python, automation

I want to make a "Auto-Reply" on Facebook Messenger using python but I don't know how to do it

If it's possible, can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`fbchat`](https://fbchat.readthedocs.io/) library, you can do something like below (the example is from the docs, and just replies back with the same message)

```py
from fbchat import log, Client

# Subclass fbchat.Client and override required methods
class EchoBot(Client):
    def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
        self.markAsDelivered(thread_id, message_object.uid)
        self.markAsRead(thread_id)

        log.info("{} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type.name))

        # If you're not the author, echo
        if author_id != self.uid:
            self.send(message_object, thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=thread_type)


client = EchoBot("<email>", "<password>")
client.listen()
```